# How to run unit tests with Codeception in Yii2?

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii2, codeception

I'm new to the Codeception framework and trying to run the unit test scripts from this directory:

```
tests/codeception/frontend/unit
```

DB configuration for testing has been done in **config-local.php**.

Now, my question is how to run the test scripts? I've tried to run the following commands from the terminal:

```
frontend tests
cd frontend
codecept build
codecept run
```

But it says **Codecept: command not found.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install Codeception via composer:

```
$ composer require "codeception/codeception"
```

From now on Codeception (with installed PHPUnit) can be run as:

```
$ php vendor/bin/codecept
```

Next, initialize your testing environment:

```
$ php vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap
```

Finally, run the following commands from the yii2 `tests/codeception/frontend` folder:

```
$ php vendor/bin/codecept build
$ php vendor/bin/codecept run
```

Follow this [Quickstart Guide](http://codeception.com/quickstart#.V08MEUp95CV) to read more about Codeception installation process.

**Important note**: if you want *codecept* command to work from the command line:

```
codecept bootstrap
codecept run
```

... then you need to configure the `$PATH` variable properly.

Answer (score 0):

The fallowing examples need installation codecept globally. This method work for the current user and linux systems.

```
composer global require "codeception/codeception=2.1.*"
composer global require "codeception/specify=*"
composer global require "codeception/verify=*"
```

You can set new path  **$PATH: in /home/user/.bashrc**

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/user/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

or set **alias in .bashrc**

```
alias codecept="/home/user/.config/composer/vendor/bin/codecept"
```

Now you can use simply

```
codecept build
codecept run
```